# Размытый UI Text / TextMesh

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-faq

Юнити из коробки имеет проблему с размыванием всех текстовых элементов юая. Как победить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина размытости в том, что юнити растеризирует текст. Не совсем понимаю для чего, но уж как есть.

Есть много вариантов костылей для решения данной проблемы, но я остановлюсь на двух вполне конкретных.

1. Заимпортить шрифт, а в настройки шрифта и задать character как Unicode + изменить Font Size.  После чего уже вешать даный шрифт на каждый текстовый обьект

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Если вам нужны пиксельные шрифты:

   Заимпортить кастомный шрифт (не важно пиксельный или нет, хоть тот же Arial, главное что бы он был заимпорчен задан вручную) и задать "Rendering mode" в "Hinted Raster"

   И на элемент текста закинуть скрипт:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine.UI;

   [ExecuteInEditMode]
   public class SetFontFilteringToPoint : MonoBehaviour
   {
       void Start ()
       {
           GetComponent<Text> ().font.material.mainTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
       }
   }
   ```

   результат:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может это и для текстур скажите? Например в эдиторе линия с высотой 1px может исчезать, а на устройстве довольно чётко видно.

Comment: Попробуй поиграться с разрешением канваса в его настройках. Возможно поможет.

Comment: Юнити растеризует текст просто потому что так решили рисовать текст в свое время. На данный момент уже довольно давно практикуется TextMeshPro с другой системой отрисовки.

Comment: И да, вешать на каждый такой элемент отдельный MonoBehaviour - слишком дорого, лучше как минимум удалять этот скрипт после отработки старта, либо вообще написать 1 общий скрипт, который будет пробегаться по всех `UI/Text`'ам.

Comment: Ну смотря сколько элементов - если немного, то и так сойдет. Но да, в идеале нужно подобрать растеризованный шрифт и сделать как в первом пути.